# "Rounded" extrude from a flat plane?

Tags: import, extrude, stl

I downloaded the model of a toe for a 3D Print project as an .stl and imported it.
I am trying to somehow extract the flat part of the model in order to give the toe a more realistic appearance with proportional editing but i wasn't very lucky.

Is there an elegant way to extrude the flat portion to a more rounded "toe-like" shape?

[image]

Any ideas, even keywords that I'd have to google are highly appreciated.

Comment: You could try to select the center of the toe and then move it outwards with _Proportional Editing_ enabled. But this is a very dense messy mesh, I highly doubt that this will work very good. Another possibility could be to sculpt it...

Comment: yeah i would sculpt it. can you share a link of where you downloaded the model if it is free. if not, nevermind.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie not free, unfortunately. Tried scuplting but I'n not very good at it. )-:

Comment: well with that type of topology you definitely have to learn how to sculpt. unless you can remesh it.